# How to permanently hide bottom panel?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know about shortcut `Control + J` but this hides the panel only for the time when I am coding. During compilation bottom panel reappears and terminal outputs its contents. Is there a way to hide the panel permanently?

Comment: you can drag all panels to the sidebar

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that you resize the panel to its minimal expression and add this to your settings.json:

```
"workbench.panel.opensMaximized": "never"
```

By looking at the options under "workbench.panel" I don't think there's a way to permanently hide it.

You could also move it to the right or left if that suits you better with:

```
"workbench.panel.defaultLocation": "right"
```